# Redmine + Merging of Newer Upgrade Version with the Older One (Older One Having Changes)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I am confused to `merge New version of Redmine with older one`.

Here, In older version, I made few changes to make it compactible to my work. But now I want to upgrade my Redmine with newer version. But I am not getting the way to merge both of this version. Here I do not want to loose my older version changes.

Older version is commited at GitHub and Newer Version Setup is at my local system.

Please suggest the way through which it is possible.

Thanks In Advance...

Comment: How did you make your changes? Did you deploy those changes - as a plugin, or direct changes to the core? What part of redmine did you modify? Which redmine version is your _work_ -version based on?

Comment: Direct changes made to core..

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just create a patch file with the changes you applied to the original version and apply the patch?

Comment: Sorry Jfrey, I dnt know how to make Patch ? Please give any reference to make such Patch. Thanks